# Why do some apps change the value of their Windows Clipboard format code?

Tags: windows, clipboard

I have an app that writes some rich text in HTML format to the Windows clipboard. The text is meant to be manually pasted in other apps, such as a browser, MS Word, Thunderbird email client, etc. Adding the content to the clipboard requires specifying a format code.

I use the `SetClipboardData(UINT uFormat, HANDLE hMem)` function. I derive `uFormat` empirically by dumping the raw contents of the clipboard and examining its format codes.

The problem is that for some apps, the format code seems to vary from one day to the next. I have observed it to be: 0xC10E, COFD, C0FE, C0FB, C10D, C11F, C0FC, C104, etc. MS Word accepts anything; Firefox and Thunderbird will reject anything other than the one specific code.

Is there a way of determining, from a program, what the format code *du jour* is?

I have reviewed [SetClipboardData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata), [Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) and [Using the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard)

Here's the code fragment:

```
        OpenClipboard();
        EmptyClipboard();
        
        int length; // text length gets set elsewhere
        HGLOBAL hglbCopy = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, length + 1); 
        LPSTR lpstr = (LPSTR)GlobalLock(hglbCopy); 
        
        memcpy(lpstr, source_text, length);
        lpstr[length] = 0;
        GlobalUnlock(hglbCopy); 

        // Place the handle on the clipboard. 
        HANDLE ret = SetClipboardData(0xC109, hglbCopy);
        CloseClipboard();
```

Here's a typical clipboard dump. In order to get this, I have to explicitly select & copy text from the app, every time, so it's not a practical way to figure out the app's format code.

```
xC009
xC1B3
xC104
xC25F
xC269
CF_UNICODETEXT
CF_TEXT
xC26A
xC013
CF_LOCALE
CF_OEMTEXT
x0
--------------------------------
xC009:
u
--------------------------------
xC1B3:
C
--------------------------------
xC104:
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000280
EndHTML:00000408
StartFragment:00000314
EndFragment:00000372
SourceURL:mailbox:///C:/Users/***/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird/Profiles/5y3ow05s.default/Mail/Local%20Folders/Vendors.sbd/X.sbd/***?number=2454
<html><body>
<!--StartFragment-->Can your team be of assistance with the following problem?<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
--------------------------------
xC25F:
<
--------------------------------
xC269:
0
--------------------------------
CF_UNICODETEXT:
C
--------------------------------
CF_TEXT:
Can your team be of assistance with the following problem?
--------------------------------
xC26A:
m
--------------------------------
xC013:

--------------------------------
CF_LOCALE:
    
--------------------------------
CF_OEMTEXT:
Can your team be of assistance with the following problem?
--------------------------------
x0:
--------------------------------
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclipboardformata

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I am not registering my own format. I want to emulate another app's format, play by its rules so to speak. My app calls 'EnumClipboardFormats', but I don't know which of the many enumerated formats belongs to the other app I'm trying to talk to.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info]. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I thought it was clear: [1] other apps only recognize certain Clipboard format codes [2] The specific value of the format seems to vary for unexplained reasons,   from one day to the next [3] I need to figure out what code the app will recognize on any given day, so I can "feed" it my stuff [4] How do I figure out what the app likes today?

Comment: You already know the answer to `2`, right? Though it's unlikely for you to put anything useful into the clipboard, if the intended target doesn't (publicly) document its protocol. So, I'm still confused what you are trying to accomplish, and I'm still not convinced that your proposed solution *weren't* an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable No, I don't know the answer to [2]. The format code mysteriously changes every day, and every day, I have to copy some random text from the app (ex: the browser), dump the Clipboard with my special diagnostic program, then manually enter the format code in my program. It's like if I tried to email you, and every day your email address changed, so I would have to phone you for your new email address.

Comment: The first comment has a link that explains, why the numeric value changes. It also explains, how registered clipboard formats should be used. In a nutshell, if you don't know the name used to register any given clipboard format, it's unlikely for you to know (or guess) the rest of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hans Passant's laconic yet incisive comment, I figured out what was missing from my code:

```
    // Retrieve or define "HTML Format": if already defined, returns the format code, else defines a new one
    UINT HTMLformat = RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format");
```

I did not realize that Clipboard formats had standard names as well as numeric values associated with them. These names are recognized by various apps.

Thank you also @IInspectable.

Comment: Custom clipboard names are the stateless information that identifies those formats. They aren't the textual alternative to a numeric value. They are the unique ID used to register or request a numeric value for a clipboard format with the system. It's the same scheme used with [registered messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew) or the [global atom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globaladdatomw) table.